# Trigger that is set off in response to another Trigger finishing

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

I just started working with SQL and I couldn't find anywhere how to create a trigger that is set off in response to another trigger finishing. Any ideas?

Also, is there a way to to have the `AFTER` expression in the `CREATE TRIGGER` statement have multiple clauses? For example:

```
CREATE TRIGGER ExampleTrigger 
 AFTER UPDATE OF thing 
    ON SampleTable OR 
 AFTER UPDATE OF boat 
    ON Sample Table ...
```

Comment: Why don't you simply add to the existing trigger?

Comment: And you can specify `AFTER UPDATE OF thing, boat ON SampleTable`

Comment: Dan, I could do that in this case but it was more of a curiosity thing to see it its possible. Tony, how do you do that if the 2nd clause wasnt in the same table?

Answer (score 0):

Refer to [Oracle Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/triggers.htm) here for further and accurate reference for triggers.

FYI, triggers are the set of commands which are executed for a particular DML event on a table in the database. This implicitly means that you cannot execute a trigger explicitly through any sort of command. The only way to invoke a trigger is by executing the overlaying DML statement.

Next, a trigger is set up on one single table only. It can be set up for multiple events like `INSERT`, `UPDATE` and/or `DELETE` but the trigger will act on just one table. You can not set up a single trigger for multiple tables. You can set up a trigger for multiple events though. You can specify like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER myTrigger
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON myTable
...
```

One more thing to note here that if you want the same code to be executed for multiple tables, it is a best practice to put it in a stored procedure or package and access that procedure from the triggers you want.